# I would like to insert data into sql table from append logs while using smslib

Tags: sql-server, netbeans, log4net-appender, smslib

I made a java application for sending SMS via Huwei Modem. Everything is working properly. I used netbeans for making this java application. According to this application, logs data will appear in Jtext Area after sending SMS to any receipt such as Receipt name, number, message and status of the message. But I would like to insert these logs data into SQL table.

I tried to mentioned below link but failed
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_database.htm

```
    {  jTextAreaLog.append(msg.toString()); }

 void appendToJTextAreaLog(String txt)
{
    jTextAreaLog.append(txt);
}
```

Comment: What is your specific problem, and what error are you getting? Or are you just asking how to do database logging for the messages? Your question is unclear as it stands.

Comment: yes, I am asking how to do databas logging for the message ?